# Mysql, actualize datetime column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql table with a timestamp column.
What we now want to do is to make the timestamps in the datetime column more recent.

When for example the newest record is 10 hours old. I want to add 10 hours to the datetime of each row. After that action the newest timestamp has value= now()

Is this possible with one query?

Comment: Please clarify, do you want all records to be updated to now?  Do you want only the latest record to be updated to now?

Comment: All records. Everything needs to be shifted to the current time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works now (tested):

```
SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) FROM yourTable INTO @a_variable;
UPDATE yourTable
SET `timestamp` = DATE_SUB(`timestamp`, INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), @a_variable) SECOND)
```

For more information see the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: error: You can't specify target table '...' for update in from clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a sub-query in the UPDATE query? (note that I've not tested this but I guess it should work)

```
UPDATE table
SET timestamp = ADDTIME(timestamp,
                       (SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp)
                        FROM table
                        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
                        LIMIT 1))
```

Comment: that 10 hours was an examle, the interval must be determed by the query

Comment: From the most recent datetime. If for example the most recent datetime is 5hours10 minutes ago, then 5hours10min must be added to each datetime

Comment: error: You can't specify target table '...' for update in from clause.

Comment: in what part of the query does the error appear, your ellipsis actually hide the most important part of the error message